# Inverse of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix has no zero entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

The inverse of the symmetric tridiagonal matrix (Toeplitz)
$$
t_{ij}=\begin{align} 
  \begin{cases}
        -2 &\quad \text{if} \,\, i=j \\
        1 &\quad\text{if} \,\, \vert i-j\vert = 1
  \end{cases} 
 \end{align}
$$

does not have any non zero entries according to online inverse calculators (I tried up to $5 \times 5-$matrices). Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression for
the $i,j$ element of the inverse of this $n\times n$ matrix
has a nice form
\begin{align}
w_{ij}&=\frac{i\,j}{n+1}-\min(i,\,j)
\tag{1}\label{1}
, 
\end{align}

so $w_{ij}$ could be zero
only if 
\begin{align} 
n&=\frac{i\,j}{\min(i,\,j)}-1
=\max(i,j)-1=n-1
,
\end{align}

and the answer follows.

Comment: How did you obtain the expression for the $i,j$ element of the inverse? just looking at it and recognizing the pattern?

Comment: @Tesla: I get it quite a while ago,
via the inverse of the 
companion circulant matrix. And also, 
as far as I remember, 
this inverse was
published is some old paper (not sure which one)
with many similar results. But 
the pattern is indeed simple
and you are right, it can be determined.